# mapview as squares

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have a problem. I have always generated api keys to display my mapviews and I have never had problems. Now, instead, every generated key makes my mapview on my smartphone displayed as little squares, as if there isn't network. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Is it v1 maps sdk? Do you he correct permission (network) ? What about log. Maps are logging about errors so look there.

Comment: Yes for the first and the second question.

Comment: 02-04 12:40:41.435: W/System.err(21483): IOException processing: 26
02-04 12:40:41.440: W/System.err(21483): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
02-04 12:40:41.440: W/System.err(21483):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)